# component communication using service

Tags: angular

In my angular 6 I am doing component communication using service:

service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
//import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()
export class ComponentCommunicationService {
  private notify = new Subject<any>();
  /**
   * Observable string streams
   */
  notifyObservable$ = this.notify.asObservable();

  constructor(){}

  public notifyOther(data: any) {
    if (data) {
      this.notify.next(data);
    }
  }
}
```

In my component P which is parent where I am checking if certain condition met it should initiate service call.

```
let isRoleFound= true;
 if(this.isRoleFound){
      this.componentCommunicationService.notifyOther({value:this.isRoleFound,option:'call from menu'});
      this.ref.detectChanges();
    }
```

service call in Child component C:

```
import {ComponentCommunicationService} from 'libs/services-module/src/commonservice/componentcommunication.service'
 constructor(
    private componentCommunicationService:ComponentCommunicationService
  ) { }

      ngOnInit() {
       this.componentCommunicationService.notifyObservable$.subscribe(res => {
          if (res.hasOwnProperty('option') && res.option === 'call from menu') {
            console.log(res.value)
            this.isRoldFound= res.value;

          }
      }) 
    }
```

Here call is getting instantiated from parent component and it goes into child component ngOnInit life cycle hook, but ultimately it does not go inside if loop and jumps out.

Please note that child component is submenu like the menu which is getting appear  only when you hover on menu item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you're asking but it's probably a timing issue. the parent is triggering the subject before the child subscribes to it. use a replay subject instead:

```
private notify = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
```

replay subjects replay their values to new subscribers.

Comment: that was it, could you please  help me with practical difference between subject and behavior subject